# post value null do this else do that PHP

Tags: jquery

I want to make a simple condition for a calendar where if one of them have been selected than both have to be selected.

For explaining more, if the startdate is selected than the enddate also have to be selected as well.
So if some one select a start date like - 5th September 2015 and than press the submit button than it should show the message that you also have to selcte the end date as well.

So the main idea is that if the post value is null for startdate and post value for enddate is not null, than it will show the message that "Please select the both date".

but it is not working for me, can someone tell me where i am making the mistake, or how I can make it work.

**Html ---**

```
<form method="post"> 
    <div class="col-md-5">
        <input type="text" name="startdate" id="startdate" class="form-control datepicker"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5">
        <input type="text" name="enddate" id="enddate" class="form-control datepicker"/>
    </div>
    <span class="error" id="date-error"></span>
    <button class="btn btn-default" id="submitButton"><i class="fa fa-sort"></i> {% trans %}Submit{% endtrans %}</button>
</form>
```

**Script ---**

```
$("#submitButton").on('click', function () {
    if ( ($( "#startdate" ).val().length == null ) && ($( "#enddate" ).val().length !== null )) {
        $("#date-error").html("Please select the both date");
        event.preventDefault();
    }
    if (( $( "#enddate" ).val().length == null ) && $( "#startdate" ).val().length !== null ) {
        $("#date-error").html("Please select the both date");
        event.preventDefault();
    } else {
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do like this

```
$("#submitButton").on('click', function () {

    startDate = $('#startdate').val();
    endDate = $('#enddate').val();

    if ( startDate == ''  && endDate == '' ) {
        $("#date-error").html("Please select the both date");
        event.preventDefault();
    }
    else if ( endDate != ''  && startDate== '') {
        $("#date-error").html("Please select start date");
        event.preventDefault();
    } else if ( startDate != ''  && endDate== '') {
        $("#date-error").html("Please select end date as well");
        event.preventDefault();
    } else {
// do your rest stuff
```

**This code will check all conditions like both dates should not be blank,start date and end date also should not be blank.**

Comment: @ChristoferHansen Glad that it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Give onsubmit on form tag. Unless & Untill, CheckValidation() is not true. Submit Will Not Process.

```
<form method="post" action='some-page.php' onsubmit="return CheckValidation();"> 
     <div class="col-md-5">
            <input type="text" name="startdate" id="startdate" class="form-control datepicker"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-5">
        <input type="text" name="enddate" id="enddate" class="form-control datepicker"/>
        </div>
        <span class="error" id="date-error"></span>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="submitButton"><i class="fa fa-sort"></i> {% trans %}Submit{% endtrans %}</button>
</form>

<script>
    function CheckValidation()
    {
        var StartDateV=$('#startdate').val();
        var EndDateV=$('#enddate').val();
        if(StartDateV=="" && EndDateV=="")      
        {
            alert("Select Both Date");
            return false;
        }
        if(StartDateV=="" && EndDateV!="")      
        {
            alert("Select Start Date");
            return false;
        }
        if(StartDateV!="" || EndDateV=="")      
        {
            alert("Select End Date");
            return false;
        }
    }
</script>
```